# How to do _cat/indices/<index_name_with_reg_ex> with JAVA API?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some indexes with name test-1-in, test-2-in, test-3-in. I want to do _cat/indices/test-*-in from JAVA API. How to do this?
I tried using the IndexAdminClient but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Given an ElasticSearch `Client` object:

```
client.admin().indices()
      .getIndex(new GetIndexRequest().indices("regex-*"))
      .actionGet().getIndices();
```

Comment: How do I call it if I have RestHighLevelClient?

Comment: How can i send multiple indices request using above method ?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Mario's answer, use the following to retrieve the indices with the Elasticsearch 6.4.0 high level REST client:

```
GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest().indices("*");
GetIndexResponse response = client.indices().get(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
String[] indices = response.getIndices();
```

Comment: You need to import `org.elasticsearch.action.admin.*` classes to make this work

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution:

```
final ClusterStateRequest clusterStateRequest = new ClusterStateRequest();
clusterStateRequest.clear().metaData(true);
final IndicesOptions strictExpandIndicesOptions = IndicesOptions.strictExpand();
clusterStateRequest.indicesOptions(strictExpandIndicesOptions);
ClusterStateResponse clusterStateResponse = client.admin().cluster().state(clusterStateRequest).get(); 
clusterStateResponse.getState().getMetadata().getIndices()
```

This will give all indexes. After that the reg ex matching has to be done manually. This is what is done for _cat implementation in elasticsearch source code.

Comment: How do I call it if I have `RestHighLevelClient`?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to cat indices with ?v option:

```
IndicesStatsRequestBuilder indicesStatsRequestBuilder = new 
IndicesStatsRequestBuilder(client, IndicesStatsAction.INSTANCE);
IndicesStatsResponse response = indicesStatsRequestBuilder.execute().actionGet();
for (Map.Entry<String, IndexStats> m : response.getIndices().entrySet()) {
   System.out.println(m);
}
```

Each of the entries contains document count, storage usage, etc. You can run this for all or filtering some index.

PD: Tested with 5.6.0 version